# how to find part of a string in lua, and split into 3 parts ? (before, matched, after)

Tags: string, split, lua, coronasdk

say I have this string, and I want to split "blue"

```
local str = "The mouse walked by the blue cheese"
```

to make it like this

```
local pre = "The mouse walked by the "    
local matched = "blue"    
local post = " cheese"
```

any suggestions for this? I searched for sometime and feel stuck.

I tried this, it works for english but seems not to work in arabic :(

```
function split(string, delimiter)
  local result = { }
  local from = 1
  local delim_from, delim_to = string.find( string, delimiter, from )
  while delim_from do
    table.insert( result, string.sub( string, from , delim_from-1 ) )
    from = delim_to + 1
    delim_from, delim_to = string.find( string, delimiter, from )
  end
  table.insert( result, string.sub( string, from ) )
  return result
end

local myStr = "The mouse walked by the blue cheese"

sep = split(myStr, "blue")
print("part1 1: "..sep[1])
print("part2 2: "..sep[2])
```

**EDITED ===================================================**

please tell me what to do in case there are multiple target words to split
for example

```
local myStr = "the mouse ate the cheese, the mouse ate the cheese!, lot of cheese there !"
```

the problem here that it splits it into multiple ones, what is needed is

> before = "the mouse ate the " after = ", the mouse ate the cheese!,
>   lot of cheese there !"

I made this, it works for english, but not for arabic

```
function split4(pString, pPattern)

    local didFind = 0

    if string.find(pString,".") then
        pString = string.gsub(pString,"%.","'.'")
    end

    if pPattern == "." then
        pPattern = "'.'"
    end

    local Table = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
    local FinalTable = {}
    local fpat = "(.-)" .. pPattern
    local last_end = 1
    local s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, 1)
    while s do
        if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
            print("Found")
            table.insert(Table,cap)
            didFind = didFind + 1
        end
        last_end = e+1
        s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, last_end)
    end
    if last_end <= #pString then
        print("Found NOT")
        cap = pString:sub(last_end)
        table.insert(Table, cap)
    end
    print(#Table)
    print("totalDidFind "..didFind)


    FinalTable[1] = Table[1]

    if (didFind > 2) then
      local endString = ""
      for z = 2 , didFind do 
        endString = endString..Table[z]..pPattern
      end
      FinalTable[2] = endString

    end

    totalDidFind = 0
    return FinalTable
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string.match()` with [lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1):

```
local str = "The mouse walked by the blue cheese"
local before, matched, after = str:match('^(.*)(blue)(.*)$')
```

And now, your `split` function is very simple:

```
function split(str, match)
    return str:match('^(.-)'..match..'(.*)$') -- Return two resulsts, but not table
end
```

P.S.: maybe, you want to find more than one matcing in text? In this case, edit your question.

Comment: Lua does not have regular expressions, but rather [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1). Similar, but the distinction should be noted.

Comment: could you please have a look at the EDITED Version ?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen Sorry for an EXTREMELY delayed reaction, but replacing first `*` with `-` makes this split on first occurrence and not the last one.